# error 2467 when I try to refer a subform control's .Form property in vba

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2013

ETA: I ran it past a colleague and he pointed out where the problem was. Answer at the bottom.

I have a parent form setup with some invisible subform controls. Each subform control is linked to a different subform at design-time, then I have some code on the parent which flies each of the subform controls to the relevant position and makes it visible for the user to do some work with it.

Here's one block of code that does this:

```
    Set Me.childRegion_MVC.Form.Recordset = rs2
    Me.childRegion_MVC.Form.cmdClearAll.Enabled = intCount > 0
    Me.childRegion_MVC.Form.cmdSetAll.Enabled = intCount < rs.RecordCount

    'Position the subform under the relevant combo box  <===== requires tailoring
    Me.childRegion_MVC.Left = Me.cboRegion.Left
    Me.childRegion_MVC.Top = Me.cboRegion.Top + Me.cboRegion.Height
    Me.childRegion_MVC.Width = Me.cboRegion.Width
    Me.childRegion_MVC.Height = cintTWIPS_CM * 4.5 ' height needs to be set in twips

    Call Me.childRegion_MVC.Form.InitRegion   ' Ensures the subform's recordset is open and binds the subform controls
    Me.childRegion_MVC.Visible = True
    Me.childRegion_MVC.SetFocus
```

and here's another:

```
    Set Me.childBusiness_MVC.Form.Recordset = rs2
    Me.childBusiness_MVC.Form.cmdClearAll.Enabled = intCount > 0
    Me.childBusiness_MVC.Form.cmdSetAll.Enabled = intCount < rs.RecordCount

    'Position the subform under the relevant combo box  <===== requires tailoring
    Me.childBusiness_MVC.Left = Me.cboBusiness.Left
    Me.childBusiness_MVC.Top = Me.cboBusiness.Top + Me.cboBusiness.Height
    Me.childBusiness_MVC.Width = Me.cboBusiness.Width
    Me.childBusiness_MVC.Height = cintTWIPS_CM * 4.5 ' height needs to be set in twips

    Call Me.childBusiness_MVC.Form.InitBusiness   ' Ensures the subform's recordset is open and bind the subform controls
    Me.childBusiness_MVC.Visible = True
    Me.childBusiness_MVC.SetFocus
```

My problem is that the first code block throws error 2467 ("the expression you entered refers to an object that is closed or does not exist.") on the very first line at run-time (where I'm setting the Recordset using a preprepared recordset object (rs2)), whereas the second block does not.

Looking at the debug window, the .Form property of the child control doesn't exist in the first case; whereas it's there in the second - so that's the proximate cause of the error, but I can't figure out *why* that form object isn't there for the first example:

- rs2 is being prepped/opened in the same way in both cases
- both subform controls (`childRegion_MVC` and `childBusiness_MVC`) have the same properties set in design mode
- both source objects (`subfrmRegion_MVC` and `subfrmBusiness_MVC` respectively) exist in the database
- I have compact/repaired and decompiled the database to purge any corruption issues that might have crept in.

But `childRegion_MVC` still breaks my form when I try to use it.

Can anyone suggest what might be going on here? I am utterly stumped.

#### +++The Solution+++

It turns out that problem was a broken recordsource on the problematic subform.

This caused the subform to have an empty recordset when it was opened as part of the parent form startup and thus it promptly closed - meaning that there was no form available when my code tried to reference it later on.

Comment: Which event are you using?

Comment: Have in mind, that a _form/subform_ opens in this sequence: _subform-form-subform_ = 3 steps. Thus, the subform is opened, closed, then the form is opened, and finally the subform is opened again.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback@Fionnuala

Comment: @Fionnuala: The code blocks I posted are in the 'On Enter' event handlers for two combo-box controls on the parent form.

Comment: @Gustav: OK thanks for the background. That suggests that for my first example the subform is not being opened the second time for some reason. Does that sound like a reasonable hypothesis?

Comment: @Tom: Thanks for the code reformatting. :)

Comment: Solution has been found. I've edited the original question to reflect the answer. 

Kudos to my colleague Colin, who spotted the problem in about 30 seconds when I ran it past him...